# Weblogic Deployment Health Status through WLST

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I need to monitor the Health Status of Deployment on Weblogic Server. i can get Server health status, threadpool status, overall server HealthStatus but didn't find Deployment Health Status. although i can get CurrentStatus which is the deployment Status (Prepared, Active etc). Please help

Answer (score 1):

The health state lives on the individual server runtimes and cannot be found on the overall domainRuntime, I think the admin server just adds up all health states.

To get to the health state of a single deployment, you can use the following code after connecting to the Adminserver over WLST:

```
domainRuntime()
appBean = getMBean("ServerRuntimes/my_server1/ApplicationRuntimes/my_app1")
appBean.getHealthState()
```

Comment: well i found HEALTH_OK there as you mention however Health showing Warning when click on Deployments in WebLogic Console, further AdminServer ThreadPool is showing 1 hogger thread and HEALTH_WARN, im little confused about Deployment Health showing in Admin Console is actually Health Status of that specific artifact (war, ear file) or Admin Server threadpool Health ??